# e-EDID header is different from standard?

Tags: hdmi, edid

I'm reading EDID information and receiving weird headers from two of my monitors.
They can both play sound, so they must be running e-EDIDs.
From what I've read, though, the header information doesn't change from an EDID to an e-EDID.

What it should be

```
00 FF FF FF FF FF FF 00
```

What I'm getting

```
00 FF FF FF 59 65 00 00
00 FF FF FF 4C 5F 00 00
```

Do e-EDIDs have different headers than EDIDs, and what specification can I read to find out more?

My reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data

http://read.pudn.com/downloads110/ebook/456020/E-EDID%20Standard.pdf

Comment: Seems your EDID is damaged or you have a problem with DDC/CI communication. Please try to read first 128 bytes block and check the checksum (127th byte)

Comment: It looks like we're reading incorrectly, but as of right now we aren't sure how. The whole EDID is just wrong. If it is a read problem, this question is done.

Comment: How you read the EDID, what OS/library?

Comment: I was using the linux/i2c-dev.h tools. For some reason, when asking for 1 byte it would return to me 2, but no matter what I did I could only receive the first byte. So I got every other byte of the edid. I'm now reading the full 128 and it works fine.